# I am moving a site collection from one farm to another

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site-collection, migration

I have been working on this for a few weeks now. I have tried many things but just can seem to get things to work correctly. I am trying to move a site collection from one farm to another. The source Farm is a signal server,  running sharepoint, sql, etc. I want to  duplicate the site collection that lives on the signal server to our test farm which has two app servers, two front end servers and a sql server (for a total of 5 server). I have tried the backup and restore with backup-spsite and restore-spsite; I got sharepiont to see that it has a site collection under the manage content databases for the correct web application.
I have also tried the following: http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=5489bebf-bd8d-4a6f-995b-3a0a456796f6&ID=83&Web=316c15c2-6bc0-464f-bda1-7ba96b4ba453

the problem is that I cannot load the page when I hit the URL that I have set up. I did have our server team set up a DNS entry to forward the url to our front end servers and I get the IIS welcome message when I hit the site. So there has to be something that I am missing when setting this up, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Got alternate access mappings all set up on the web app?

Comment: Oh, also, if yuo're test farm is on a different domain you'll need to reset the Site Collection Administrator via Central Admin for the site collection in order to get access.

Comment: If you are seeing the IIS welcome message it means that SharePoint isn't listening on that URL:Port

Comment: Can you browse to http://yourNewServerName/sites/yoursite collection? OR http://yourNewServerName/?

Comment: content deployment isn't the way to approach this. I'd say you're probably missing the AAMs and the site bindings in IIS for this to work.

Comment: Are you restoring the site collection to the root of the web app? To get started create an entry in your host file with the appropriate name and Ip on the server. Ensure that the name is set as one of the ALternate access mappings as James suggests